# Tensorflow example--loss INCREASES but it successfully converges

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on some details in tensorflow understanding.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why my cost/loss is increasing while the model continues to converge.  I've tried various conditions with learning rates, different losses (one is commented out), etc and cannot understand why the cost is increasing, but the model continues to update towards the correct parameters (W, b--see output below).  Everyone at work said my model wasn't training, but there is something else here that I am not understanding.  This has persisted across 2 separate machines and OS systems

If I sent the learning rate super low, the loss always decreases, but the model never reaches the 'target' outputs (understandable--low learning rate, slow convergence).  What I am not getting is that even though I can get the model to coverge and even stop on the proper parameters, my loss up until convergence is not corresponding to proper behavior--it should stabilize once W,b stabilize (I can get it to stabilize once W,b reach correct values) and if  loss is increasing, then W,b should be moving AWAY from the 'true' values.

It seems to be a function of the spread of the data--for noise_spread=0.1, the problem exists.  For noise spread 0.5, it is much better behaved.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = numpy.random
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50
# Generate synthetic data
N = 100
w_true = 5
b_true = 2
noise_scale = .1
x_np = np.random.rand(N, 1)
noise = np.random.normal(scale=noise_scale, size=(N, 1))
# Convert shape of y_np to (N,)
y_np = np.reshape(w_true * x_np  + b_true + noise, (-1))
train_X=x_np
train_Y =y_np
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]
# tf Graph Input# tf Gr 
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")
# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)
# Mean squared error
#cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))
cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y,pred)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Start training# Start 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

        #Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), 
                "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

    #Graphic display
    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.plot(train_X, sess.run(W) * train_X + sess.run(b), label='Fitted line')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

My output is this:

```
Epoch: 0050 cost= 4.118685722 W= 2.9452877 b= 2.4476562
Epoch: 0100 cost= 3.944761038 W= 3.3132584 b= 2.7724605
Epoch: 0150 cost= 4.055146694 W= 3.511169 b= 2.8108914
Epoch: 0200 cost= 4.153135777 W= 3.6549997 b= 2.7731476
Epoch: 0250 cost= 4.238377571 W= 3.7775438 b= 2.7175744
Epoch: 0300 cost= 4.317091465 W= 3.888368 b= 2.6601844
Epoch: 0350 cost= 4.391473293 W= 3.9905539 b= 2.605233
Epoch: 0400 cost= 4.462153912 W= 4.0853305 b= 2.5536873
Epoch: 0450 cost= 4.529345512 W= 4.1734138 b= 2.5056264
Epoch: 0500 cost= 4.593110561 W= 4.255291 b= 2.4608996
Epoch: 0550 cost= 4.653543472 W= 4.331433 b= 2.4192963
Epoch: 0600 cost= 4.710726738 W= 4.402243 b= 2.3806055
Epoch: 0650 cost= 4.764744759 W= 4.468083 b= 2.344631
Epoch: 0700 cost= 4.815713882 W= 4.5293126 b= 2.311165
Epoch: 0750 cost= 4.863757610 W= 4.586264 b= 2.2800498
Epoch: 0800 cost= 4.908967018 W= 4.639206 b= 2.2511148
Epoch: 0850 cost= 4.951507092 W= 4.6884646 b= 2.224208
Epoch: 0900 cost= 4.991419315 W= 4.734207 b= 2.1991928
Epoch: 0950 cost= 5.028926373 W= 4.776786 b= 2.1759307
Epoch: 1000 cost= 5.064134598 W= 4.816405 b= 2.154287
Optimization Finished!
Training cost= 5.0641346 W= 4.816405 b= 2.154287
```

Comment: Figured out one part of the problem: Every element of Y is subtracted with every other element of pred because the dimensions are transpose of each other. Change to: tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y,tf.squeeze(pred))

Comment: actually I believe that is the source of the problem--dim of Y is incorrect.  If i correct them, loss behaves 'as expected' --i discovered it by trying to manually calculate loss separately since I knew W, b and of course, the dimensions did not match up.  Sadly I got this from a book tutorial (O'Reilly).